# Coverting epub to html file using pypandoc

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pypandoc
html=pypandoc.convert_file("corona.epub",'html',outputfile="corona1.html")
assert html==""
```

I'm tried to convert an epub file into HTML file but the output is only text HTML. there is no image in this file. how to convert HTML with image?

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
$ unzip "corona.epub"
```

from your command line, and it will expand all the xhtml files inside the epub

Answer (score 0):

```
import pypandoc
import os

os.environ.setdefault('PYPANDOC_PANDOC', '/opt/homebrew/bin/pandoc')


filepath = "<full path of your epub file...>"
pathname, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
targetfilename = 'index.html'


pypandoc.convert_file(filepath,
                  format='epub',
                  to='html5',
                  extra_args=[
                      '--read=epub',
                      f'--extract-media={pathname}',
                      '--wrap=none'
                  ],
                  encoding='utf-8',
                  outputfile=pathname + '/' + targetfilename,
                  filters=None,
                  verify_format=True
                 )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@xiaolai answer as it stands still doesn't include images or styles. It works if you include two more arguments in the 'extra_args' bit. They are --standalone and --embed-resources.

Then it does what you asked for. :)

[I got this from another post  (and tried it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67024018/pandoc-epub-to-html-include-images-styles-in-the-single-page-html)