# Pandoc epub to html: include images & styles in the single page HTML

Tags: html, pandoc, epub

I use the following command to produce a single page .html file for a .epub file,

```
pandoc -f epub -t html -o output.html  ./book.epub
```

But the .html file is lacking images. Is there a way to tell pandoc or something to embed the images in them? Just like Chrome's [SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle) produces.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `--resource-path=` also `--self-contained` might be useful.

Comment: @AllanWind Ah, `--self-contained` does it, thank you.

Comment: But ... can the ebook's styles (CSS) can be include as well? Pandoc currently generates an unstyled HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--embed-resources` to instruct Pandoc to include images and stylesheets (and ...) in the HTML as data URIs. See the [official manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--embed-resources) for more information

The `--standalone` option should also be used to include the HTML header and footer

```
pandoc -f epub -t html -o output.html  ./book.epub --standalone --embed-resources
```

Comment: I am getting "Unknown option `--embed-resources`" in 2023, is there a replacement for that option?

Comment: I have tested it on Pandoc 3.0.1, I think it's more likely you have too old version than that they removed it in 3.1. The older version had a similar `--self-contained` option

Comment: Thanks for checking, I have apparently 2.5. Sorry for a false alarm.